# Yii2: Select all options on dropDownList without extension

Tags: javascript, php, yii

How can I add to the dropDowList the option to select all without using an extension? I need to be able to mark one or all at once, in the image I show how it should look.

[image]

I have this code:

```
<?php

   echo CHtml::dropDownList('client', '', (array) $all_client, array(
        'empty' => 'Select All',
        'class' => "form-control selectpicker",
        'id' => "f_client",
        'style' => "width: 150px;",
        'data-live-search' => "true",
        'onchange' => 'myFunction()',
        'multiple' => 'multiple'
    ));

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to publish the answer, it may be useful to another person. Using the bootstrap select plugin I just had to add:

```
'data-actions-box' => 'true'
```

and it worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

You must do it with javascript. Add event listener to select all, and after click get all items and add it to input field.